# Unable to open PDF files in app view in Capacitor Ionic

Tags: capacitor, capacitor-plugin

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

const { Browser } = Plugins;

Browser.open({ url: 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf', windowName:'_self' });
```

When the url is specified as a link to a website, it works fine but doesnt when specified a PDF. Could someone please suggest if any changes required ? Do i need to specify the rel ? If yes how ? There is no such key to be passed in open call. Response received is 'NO enabled plugin supports this MIME type'.

Comment: Try using ```window.open(http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf)```
You don't need any plugin to use ```window.open```

Comment: @ShinichiKudo window.open('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf','_parent'); or  window.open('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf'); gives the same error 
<html><body><!-- no enabled plugin supports this MIME type --></body></html>

Comment: @richaSingh Is this for Android or iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Browser` plugin from Capacitor should work fine for this. Try without specifying `windowName`.

```js
// Capacitor v2
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Browser } = Plugins;
Browser.open({ url: 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf'});

// or for Capacitor v3
import { Browser } from '@capacitor/browser';
Browser.open({ url: 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf'});
```

[image]

Comment: It doesnt open in the app for me , opens in a new tab instead. Can i take a look at your code ?Code pen ?  BTW I'm using Ionic/React :5.4.0 and capacitor/core:2.4.2.

Comment: I could find a similar post on ionicForum https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-capacitor-browser-api-opening-new-tab/192708

Comment: Also, is it possible to download the PDF too using Capacitor Browser ?

Comment: @richaSingh How are you testing? Simulator or browser?

Comment: Was testing in browser, works fine in simulator . Thanks :)

Comment: When my file is placed within public folder, i get 'Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP'. It seems to work fine when loaded through anchor tag's href attribute but when i pass the same url to Browser.open, it raises CORS error. any idea why and a possible workaround ?

onclick={()=>Browser.open({url:`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/sample.pdf`})

Comment: The URL you're using is likely violating CORs rules. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local

Comment: ya but why ? And when tried converting from base64 to blobURL, it throws error .
blobUrl Richa blob:capacitor://localhost/86b2ea43-d5c5-4600-bf69-ddd270b0d29f
ERROR MESSAGE:  {"errorMessage":"","message":"Invalid URL"}

Comment: @AnantaPrasad What error are you getting. This plugin works for iOS & Android.

Comment: It doest not preview the pdf on downloads directly in android

Answer (score -2):

InAppBrowser will not pdf files. you will have to use it in some other way,

**first** you can simply add a href this will open user default browser.. like for android it will open this link in android and for ios it will use safari.

```
<a  href="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf">open pdf</a>
```

**Second** way is to use a plugin for document viewer .. i have added its link below

```
constructor(private document: DocumentViewer) { }

const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
  title: 'My PDF'
}

this.document.viewDocument('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf', 'application/pdf', options)
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/document-viewer